# Circular System, how to get numbers back into stock 1

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am creating a system dynamic and agent-based model for my dissertation.
Numbers generated through the different flows must be added back to the start to continue through the process.
For example, numbers flow from a parameter to stock 1, which goes through a flow process at a specific rate to stock 2. From stock 2, there is another flow process based on a particular rate to stock 3. The numbers from stock 3 need to go back into stock 1 to repeat the process.

Methods I have tried have been adding flows, links, and changing the initial value of stock 1.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Updated:
Added screenshots.
I think it is because of the difference between the two flows, e.g. a -9 based on the difference between flow and flow3 as shown in the screenshot.

Screenshots:
[Graph of Stock 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woMPN.png)

[Model as a whole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcULI.png)

Comment: What are the issues you get when using the methods you tried?

Comment: @Jaco-BenVosloo The issue I keep getting is that Stock 1 does not increase from the return from stock 3. Stock 1 continues on a downward slope. What I would like to see is small increases and then a decrease. I might be overthinking the matter as I looked at it again. If the number from stock 3 comes back to stock 1, then the flow rate is the difference between the two flows, e,g. 1 - 0.3 or 0.7 net loss. I might not see the change due to the scale in time being larger than the change.

Comment: Please add more detail and screenshot if possible

Comment: @Jaco-BenVosloo I added a couple of screenshots and a graph from stock.

Comment: this model is perfectly fine... what are you looking for really? What kind of help do you want? What are your expectations of the model behavior and what is the difference between what you expect and what you get?

Answer (score 1):

In system dynamics, if you want to have a circular system (feedback loop) it needs to contain as a minimum 1 stock inside the loop, which means that there is at least 1 delay in the feedback loop

[image: circular system]

Comment: Thank you for the information, but it is not entirely relevant as it was mentioned there was more than one stock in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain your model
stock has an outflow of 20 (flow), and an inflow of 11 (flow3)... this produces a net outflow of 9/timeUnit
This is what you see in the graph... and it doesn't even matter if your system is circular or not, that stock will lose 9/timeUnit forever.

Your wording is very strange when you say "numbers are generated and numbers are flowing"... it's not numbers that flow through your system... you can't really say "i have 3 numbers per minute flowing into a pool of numbers"

In your model, the "numbers" are definitely going back to the initial stock, but system dynamics is like water flowing, it is not a discrete paradigm, so you will not see the same "numbers" going back because system dynamics doesn't differentiate what individual "numbers" are flowing.

It's so weird already to have to use the word numbers to be consistent with your question.

So in order to have a better answer, you will need to specify:

- what is the behavior you see in here
- what is the behavior you expect, and how it differs from what you see
- what would you need to see in the system in order to say "yes,  my system in working exactly as expected"
- It would help if you let us know what your system represents, and if you use names that represents what is flowing through the system (instead of using numbers, stock and flow, because any explanation becomes confusing)